# How to convert audio and read pcm data?

Tags: c++, libav

I have an MP3 file, which is opened fine. the `AVCodecContext` is properly filled.
For the PCM data codec, I have an `output_codec_ctx` :

```cpp
output_codec_ctx(avcodec_alloc_context3(avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S32LE)),delete_av)
```

I want to read the MP3 file and stream it to my speakers. The speakers expect PCM data.
So the idea is to decode the MP3 file and then encode it to PCM.
According to [this](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.0/group__lavc__encdec.html)

I need to use `avcodec_send*` and `avcodec_receive*` repeatedly:

My function that fills my streaming buffer(s) looks like this:

```cpp
while(stream.current_buffer_position < audio_stream::buffer_size-1) {
    std::unique_ptr<AVPacket,void(*)(void*)> send_packet = std::unique_ptr<AVPacket,void(*)(void*)>(av_packet_alloc(),delete_av);
    std::unique_ptr<AVFrame,void(*)(void*)> send_frame = std::unique_ptr<AVFrame,void(*)(void*)>(av_frame_alloc(),delete_av);
    std::unique_ptr<AVPacket,void(*)(void*)> receive_packet = std::unique_ptr<AVPacket,void(*)(void*)>(av_packet_alloc(),delete_av);
    std::unique_ptr<AVFrame,void(*)(void*)> receive_frame = std::unique_ptr<AVFrame,void(*)(void*)>(av_frame_alloc(),delete_av);
    if(int read_result = av_read_frame(stream.input_format_ctx.get(), send_packet.get());read_result != 0) {
        if(read_result == AVERROR_EOF && stream.mode == stream_mode::loop) {
            av_seek_frame(stream.input_format_ctx.get(),stream.stream_to_decode,0,AVSEEK_FLAG_FRAME);
        }else {
            break;
        }
    }

    int send_result = avcodec_send_packet(stream.input_codec_ctx.get(), send_packet.get());
    if(send_result != 0) {
        char buff[64];
        log_error(av_make_error_string(buff, 64 ,send_result));
        continue;
    }
    send_result = avcodec_send_frame(stream.input_codec_ctx.get(),send_frame.get());
    if(send_result != 0) {
        char buff[64];
        log_error(av_make_error_string(buff, 64 ,send_result));
        continue;
    }
    int receive_result = avcodec_receive_frame(stream.output_codec_ctx.get(), receive_frame.get());
    if(receive_result != 0) {
        char buff[64];
        log_error(av_make_error_string(buff, 64 ,receive_result));
        continue;
    }
    receive_result = avcodec_receive_packet(stream.output_codec_ctx.get(), receive_packet.get());
    if(receive_result != 0) {
        char buff[64];
        log_error(av_make_error_string(buff, 64 ,receive_result));
        continue;
    }
    auto remaining_buffer_size = audio_stream::buffer_size - stream.current_buffer_position;
    auto copy_size = std::min(remaining_buffer_size,(std::size_t)receive_frame->linesize);
    std::memcpy(&stream.buffers[stream.current_read_buffer][stream.current_buffer_position],receive_frame->data,copy_size);
    stream.current_buffer_position += copy_size;
    size+=copy_size;
}
```

In the first two loop iterations, `avcodec_send_packet` returns success, aswell as `avcodec_send_frame`.
`avcodec_receive_frame` however returns `invalid argument`.

In every subsequent iteration `avcodec_send_packet` returns `resource temporarily unavailable`.

What am I missing?